# Foreach Loop grabbing JSON data

Tags: php, html, json, foreach

Could someone assist me in helping me display more than 1/2 results?

Here is my code:

```
$url = "http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=debt%20management&window=a&perpage=10";
$jsonfile = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($jsonfile);


foreach($obj as $result) {
    echo $obj->response->list[0]->trackback_permalink;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $obj->response->list[0]->trackback_author_nick;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $obj->response->list[0]->content;
    echo "<br /><br />";

}
?>
```

*Note: I have taken out my API key.

Using that code it shows two of the same results.

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Not enough information. Please edit your question and poste the JSON structure you receive.

Comment: You can view it here: http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=debt%20management&window=a&perpage=10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over `$obj` which is the top-level object containing two elements (`request` and `response`). Since you probably want to iterate over the response list, this is what you need:

```
foreach($obj->response->list as $result) {
    echo $result->trackback_permalink;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $result->trackback_author_nick;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $result->content;
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks for this. Im new to JSON, so i'm not aware of simple things etc.. Thanks alot for this though :) - Really appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump` and `print_r` are your friends to have a closer look at data structures in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just saw it:

remove the `$obj++` ! You increment *twice* during each loop run. Once by the `foreach()` loop iterating itself, and once by manually iterating.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to take that out, even with that out, it still only shows 2 results?